# How to proper wait for a return before making any action?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with some await/async functions. So I have the following function which `pdfData` is never different than `undefined`; What I want to do is that after all the process of creating the pdf file sign it with s3, upload it to s3 then delete it from temp folder to return the status and url to download.

Can anyone let me know what am I missing?

```
const pdfData = await pdf
  .create(content, options)
  .toFile(`./src/services/temp/${fileName}`, async function(error, result) {
    if (error) return console.log(error);

    const file = result.filename;
    // requestSignS3
    const awsSign = await signS3(
      `statements/${fileName}`,
      "application/pdf"
    );
    // upload document to S3
    const uploadStatus = await uploadDocumentToS3(awsSign, file);
    // delete file from temp folder
    fs.unlink(file, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    // set data to return
    const data = {
      status: uploadStatus,
      url: awsSign.url
    };

    return data;
  });

console.log(pdfData);
```

Comment: Just a sanity check question... is your `await pdf ...` inside an async function?

Comment: yes, all this function is inside try catch

Comment: ?? A try/catch is not an async function

Comment: Yeah sorry the try catch is wrapped in an async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the promise (or async-await) recipe mixed with the callback recipe. Don't.

1. Does `toFile` return a promise? If so, then we're pretty much already there:

```
const pdfFile = await pdf
  .create(content, options)
  .toFile(`./src/services/temp/${fileName}`);

const pdfData = await /* everything async you want to do with pdfFile goes there */(pdfFile);
```

2. If `toFile` doesn't return a promise, you need to promisify it, either with the `promisify` library, or manually. It would basically look like this:

```
const toFilePromise = new Promise(function(reject, resolve) => {
    pdf.create(content, options)
        .toFile(`./src/services/temp/${fileName}`, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
});
```

Now, the `toFilePromise` is something that can be awaited. After, you can extract filename, `await signS3(`, etc.

Comment: so I am using `html-pdf` to render the handlebars to pdf and `.toFile` I can see that take in two params `export interface CreateResult {
    toBuffer(callback: (err: Error, buffer: Buffer) => void): void;
    toFile(callback: (err: Error, res: FileInfo) => void): void;
    toFile(filename?: string, callback?: (err: Error, res: FileInfo) => void): void;
    toStream(callback: (err: Error, stream: fs.ReadStream) => void): void;
  }`

Comment: Edited with more details.